# How to drilldown a pie highchart into multiple containers using renderTo or redraw method?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

I want to drilldown my chart into another container. I have 3 to 4 levels of drilldown in my chart and I want all of them to display in different containers.
How can I do that in the simplest way without making duplications in my code and without making it complex.`
    
        
            HighChart Drilldown Example

```
</head>
<body>

        <div id="container0" style="min-width: 900px; height: 500px; margin: 0 "></div>
        <div id="container1" style="min-width: 900px; height: 300px; margin: 0 "></div>
        <div id="container2" style="min-width: 900px; height: 100px; margin: 0 "></div>

    <script>
        var chartType;
        function getTitle()
           {
            var e = document.getElementById("getTitleId");
            chartType = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
            return chartType; 
           }  
       var defaultTitle = "Sales Summary [Quarterly]";
       var drilldownTitle = "  Sales";
       var chart = Highcharts.chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container0',
                        type: 'pie',
                        marginLeft:120,
                        options3d: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        alpha: 45,
                                        beta: 0
                                   },
                        events: {
                            drilldown: function(e) {
                                chart.setTitle({ text:  e.point.name  + drilldownTitle  });



                            },
                            drillup: function(e) {
                                chart.setTitle({ text: defaultTitle });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                     title: {
        text:defaultTitle
    },
    credits : {
        enabled : false
    },
      events:{
        drilldown: function(e)
        {

            chart.setTitle({text: e.point.name}, {text: ''});

        },
        drillup: function(e){
            if(e.seriesOptions.name == topLevelSeriesName) {
                chart.setTitle({text: topLevelTitle}, {text: topLevelSubtitle});
            }
            else {
                chart.setTitle({text: e.seriesOptions.name}, {text: ''});
            }
        }

},  

             xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },   


    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: `{point.tooltips}<br>Sales:{point.y}</b>`
    },

    plotOptions: {
        showInLegend: true,



        pie: {allowPointSelect: true,
        depth: 35,},
        series: {
            borderWidth: 50,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type:'pie',
        name: 'Quarterly',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
        {
            name: 'QUARTER 1',
            y:3061997,
            drilldown: 'quarter1'
        },
        {
            name: 'QUARTER 2',
            y:56608868,
            drilldown: 'quarter2'
        }
        ]
    }],

    drilldown: {
        drillUpButton: {
                            relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
                            position: {
                                y: 0,
                                x: 0
                            },},
        series: [

            {
            id: 'quarter1',
            name: 'MONTHLY',
            data: [

            {
                name:'FEBRUARY',
                y:139353,



                drilldown: 'february'
            },
            {
                name:'MARCH',
                y:2922643,
                drilldown: 'march'
            }
            ]
        },
        {   
            type:'pie',
            id: 'quarter2',
            name: 'MONTHLY',
            data: [
            {
                name: 'APRIL',
                y:21781659,
                drilldown: 'april'
            },
            {
                name:'MAY',
                y:19387600,
                drilldown: 'may'
            },
            {
                name:'JUNE',
                y:15439608,
                drilldown: 'june'
            }
            ]
        }
]
    }






        });
    </script>
</body>
```

`
How can I drilldown this chart into different container on each click event of drilldown?

Here's the link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob3z8n4c/6/)

Comment: What do you mean by drilldown into a different container? What happens to the container that the click originated from? Are you trying to have a drilldown action on one chart apply a filter for a different chart?

Comment: Nothing happens to the original conatiner.
It just acts like a source for the drilldown to be loaded in the new container..

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you do not even need to use drilldown module. You can create specific chart on point's click event. Take a look at the example below.

```
click: function() {
  var index = this.index;

  Highcharts.chart('container' + (index + 1), {
    series: [additionalSeries[index]]
  });
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/n8jexo6m/